# Silly question about android activty lifecycle

Tags: android, service, android-activity, resume

I have activity+service classes.

When program runs activity will be shown and service will be started in `onCreate`  method of activity.

When I clicked on HOME button of virtual machine, HOME SCREEN will be appear but activity will have been gone

1. at this point, I wonder that program in which situation -paused/stopped- ???
2. what happened to the service? (is it still running?)
3. how can I bring the activity to front using the service?

Thank you...

Comment: If u start the application again the same screen will come.. Activity ll be in paused state...

Comment: To track the livecycle, override the methods onStart(), onRestart(), onResume(), onPause(), onStop(), onDestroy() and create a log entry in the body.

Comment: @devA Not necessarily, the Android framework may have destroyed the `Activity` to obtain resources.

Comment: @Gary Buyn.. Yes nothing is guaranteed... it depends on the situation...but its true for some case.....

Comment: also take a look at smith324's answer in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569936/android-services-and-activities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well in your case for the activity if you press the home button it is paused. and by launching it again with pressing the home button it just resumes it.

for the service: it depends how your service is started..

**if you start the service with startService(intent) then your service is running until:**

a) you explicitly stop it by calling stopService.

b) android kills it

c) you call selfStop from inside the service

**if you start the service with bindService() without calling startService() then the service will:**

a) run untill the activity is destroyed (not paused, so this means it will keep running if you press the home button) and this also means you need to call unbind().

b) android kills it

c) untill you call selfStop from inside the service

to bring the activity to foreground you need to call an intent and set the flag i believe it was launch from history or something like that.... you will have to check the docs.

intent.addFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT); <- i think
or this one -> FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY

Answer (score 1):

See below the activity flow, hope it helps

[image: The activity flow]

Answer (score 0):

The state of your `Activity` (and `Service`) could vary depending on what else is happening. If the Android system needed resources it may have destroyed your `Activity` (and possibly also your `Service`) to obtain them. You should read up on:

- The [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html) and
- The [Service Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html)

In the `Activity` diagram (also in Mark Bakker's answer) pay particular attention to the box containing the text 'Other applications need memory'.